Horror movie with a lot of monsters
I want to find the name of the movie that have this famous scene:
"It's about some armed people, might be some sort of PMC, security guys or even a police force, they are in a corridor with a bunch of doors, if I remember it right it looks like elevator doors, they proceed into the corridor and then all the doors open, then a lot of creatures come out killing them, pretty gore, I can remember 2 monsters in particular, a giant snake and a gargoyle splitting someone in half, the corridor get's all dirty with blood."
That's all I could remember of the scene, it was some time ago that I saw it while looking for a site with numbered supernatural beings, which I don't recall either, sorry if it's not detailed enough or if I mixed something up my memory is not my strongest point, hoping someone gets it! Thanks for your time!

Cabin in the Woods (2012) horror comedy, you're referring to the climactic scene toward the end when the two remaining protagonists let all the monsters escape


This was my first thought when reading the description above as well.
